# php syntax errors on simple sendmail code

Tags: php, syntax, sendmail

So dreamweaver is telling me i have syntax errors at lines 5, 8, 10 and 12. But i can't see why?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) (
    $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['FirstName'] .$_POST['LastName'] ."\n" 
    .'Email: ' .$_POST['Email'] ."\n" 
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['Message'];
    mail('email@me.com', 'Message from website', $msg);
    header('location: contact-thank-you.php');
)
else (
header('location: contact.php');
exit(0);
)
)       
?>
```

Comment: Run the code and see if PHP complains about it.

Comment: you are using `(` and `)` instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['FirstName'] .$_POST['LastName'] ."\n" 
    .'Email: ' .$_POST['Email'] ."\n" 
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['Message'];
    mail('email@me.com', 'Message from website', $msg);
    header('location: contact-thank-you.php');
}
else {
header('location: contact.php');
exit(0);
}
```

You need to have `{` and `}` instead of `(` & `)`

Comment: An explanation of the problem would be helpful instead of a *spot-the-difference*.

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
if () {
  ....
} else {
  ....
}

other than

if () (
  ....
) else (
  ....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you concatenation string between firstname and lastname. I suppose the error exists in string concatenation. try doing "Name: " . $_POST['firstname'] . " " .$_POST['lasname'] . "\n" ....
You have formed the string with two different quotes to form a string at one place you are using single quote and further you are using double quote try cleaning it. Always use consistent quotes and its is always a good idea to use double quotes for string concatenation. It actually improves code readability.

Hope this helps